# How does one protect an AES password that is used on the client?

Tags: javascript, aes

I want to use Stanford's implementation of AES here:

http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/

However, it is essentially useless if I use it as they suggest

> SJCL is easy to use: simply run sjcl.encrypt("password", "data") to
>   encrypt data, or sjcl.decrypt("password", "encrypted-data").

As anyone can simply load my site, look at the java script and use the password to decrypt the data the same way I would.

How do i make this solution useful?

Comment: Ask the user to supply the password?

Comment: Better just store it on a cookie like Remember Me does...it has to go somewhere.

Comment: Be careful with that idea -- make absolutely certain the user knows you're going to store the passphrase in a cookie on their computer before doing so. (Better yet, offer an option to prompt the user for the passphrase every time you need it.)

Comment: Actually since the users password must pass through the client..that is a good key to use...better than using a cookie...because it never hits the hard-drive.it's in memory(RAM) for a brief bit before being encrypted...using the encrypted object as the key is how PHP crypt works as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit more back-and-forth I think I understand what you want to know better enough to give you an answer. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

In general, managing symmetric keys is very difficult. There are two primary uses for symmetric ciphers:

- Protecting the privacy of stored data for later use by the same person. If you use an online backup service, you really hope that your data is encrypted on the client *before* being uploaded to the online service -- you do not want them to have access to your data in plaintext. But when you go to decrypt the data in the future, *you're* the one to supply the key. This means you could store the key on offline media (CD-R, USB memory stick, SD card, little notebook next to the monitor...) or online (browser cookie, OS-supplied keychain of some sort, or standard file...).
- Protecting the privacy of data while in transit between two parties. One party encrypts the data and the other party decrypts the data. This is how spies communicate, how TLS provides HTTPS client-to-server security, how SSH provides client-to-server security. In this case, both parties need to agree to the key that will be used, and this can be done with [Diffie-Hellman-Merkle Key Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) or using a [public-key encryption algorithm such as RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) to allow one party to encrypt a randomly-generated session key in a way that it can only be decrypted by the other party.

The library you have found looks like it is highly optimized for the first case -- allowing users to encrypt their data for you to store and then retrieve for them later. Because they use a [password based key derivation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) it is prepared to handle the poor passwords that are available through simply typing on a keyboard -- the function will allow building safer keys out of just what a human can (or will) type on a keyboard.

Of course, it *could* be used for the second case, but presumably you're using this in a browser that has full TLS support, which can provide for end-to-end security in case you choose to use both client certificates and server certificates.

If you chose to allow the user to store encrypted data through your software, you should definitely make clear where the decryption key is being stored. I could see a use case for having a cookie on the browser store the key -- so that the user does not need to re-type it when they want their data. But if they change machines or browsers, they'll need to know the password so they can again retrieve their data.

However, if a user thinks their data is "secure", perhaps they should re-type their key every time they want to use their data. That way, the user alone is responsible for the security of the key; browser flaws that allow exposure of cookie data -- or locally-running malicious code -- cannot simply read the key off disk.

The downside of all this, of course, is that there isn't an easy answer available: you have to decide between the simplicity of storing passwords *or* the safety of not storing passwords.

Comment: This will all be transparent to the user.  To login they have to supply a password..just like gmail or facebook.  I will use that for the key and keep it saved ( one-way encrypted of course )  in some sort of session variable.  I'm only trying to increase security for users that request it.  This accomplishes that unobtrusively.  Having encrypted data increases privacy.  Having a key not stored on a hard-drive increases this further.  Having it removed from a session variable would increase it even further but I don't want to add in the obtrusiveness.

Comment: So out of 3 levels...i'm going with 2 out of preference.  Excellent info. thanks.  I was going to ask why the library is so long..it's b.c. they have much more then AES stuff...as you pointed out.